# Ember Cli append HTML to body tag, before the script tags

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

The default ember cli app would add html to body tag, after script tags.

So, it will be kinda like this:

```
<body>
    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/compile.js"></script>
    <header>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </header>
</body>
```

I want to put the code right after the body tag, **before** the script tags:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </header>
    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/compile.js"></script>     
</body>
```

I can specify the rootElement in app.js, but if I specify body tag, it still adds the html code below script tags. The only way it works is if i set kind of a 'wrapper' like so:

```
rootElement: '.wrapper'
```

and the result will be:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/compile.js"></script>     
</body>
```

But why the hell on earth would I need this wrapper ? (it is like a stone age, i hate that approach)

Is there a way to specify the location **right after the body tag**, before the scripts tag?

Comment: I'm going to be the ass of the group and ask why (mostly I'm just curious)?

Comment: @Kingpin2k For me it is cleaner & logical. Html first, scripts below. And a wrapper for that is ridiculous.

Comment: What version of `ember-cli` are you on? The default is right before the `</body>` tag. Are you building with the environment set to production?

Comment: @Patsy the latest, 0.1.2. Yes, it is right before the closing `</body>` tag & i want after the opening `<body>` tag

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it but if you really want to do this find your `index.html` file and move the script tags above `{{content-for 'body'}}`

Comment: @PatsyIssa nope, that does not work, checked

Comment: Just built and it gives the desired result, can I ask why are you doing this?

Comment: @PatsyIssa for me it does not work, html is again below the `<script>` tags. tried twice, both dev and prod env. Why i want that - second comment above.

Comment: The html is generated dynamically after the scripts have run, it's not like it's delivered and parsed that way.  Technically the script tags could be deleted after the page has loaded and it'd make no difference.  If you want such fine-grain control of pieces that have no difference in how the page is displayed you'll likely have to use some sort of wrapper hack like you've done already.

Comment: @Kingpin2k the html could be just appended right after the body tag, not after all tags in the body, thats all. but, it can't be done in an easy way :(